# PySpark : Name a new dataframe column from column value

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I need to create new columns in my dataframe and name these columns from dataframe values. Something like this :

```
new_df = df.withColumn( concat('col_',df['col1']) , df['col2']+df['col3'])
```

But it tells that i can't use column object in the name

Comment: It's like, for each value in col1, a new column has to be created, correct?

Comment: @Suresh This is exactly what i wanted to compute and your answer helped me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this helps,

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
new_df = df.withColumn('combcol',F.concat(F.lit('col_'),df['col1'])).groupby('col1').pivot('combcol').agg(F.first('col1')+F.first('col2'))
```